# node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ViewportScroller'

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm facing this strange issue while running **ionic 3** app. I gone through the several posts like this but none can help.

Following is the project config,

**Ionic Framework: 3.9.2**

**Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.11**

**Angular Core: 5.0.0**

**Angular Compiler CLI: 5.0.0**

**Node: 8.11.3**

**OS Platform: Windows 10**

**Navigator Platform: Win32**

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 9):

Do you have Angular Router installed with an incompatible version? If I make a new Ionic app it has Angular core, etc. at **5.2.11** and installing router (npm i @angular/router) installs **6.1.2**, which leads to:

```
typescript: .../ionicapp/node_modules/@angular/router/src/router_scroller.d.ts, line: 8
Module '"F:/ionicapp/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ViewportScroller'.
```

Installing Angular router at 5.2.11 corrects this error.

Comment: This should also resolve package.json for next npm i. Thank you @Kevin